# An IMDB_dataset is given, I need to find-

Tags: r

IMDB data set is given-
Extract the unique genres and its count and store in data frame with index key.
please help me out how to store in data frame with index key. I am new to R.

I tried to create data frame but not able to get how to get index value? This is confusing me

unique values of genres

```
unique(df$Genre)
```

count of unique values of variable Genre

```
length(unique(df$Genre))
```

Extract the unique genres and its count and store in data frame with index key.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data with `dput` and exactly what do you mean by index? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) how to formulate this and future questions better.

Comment: Please try `table(df$Genre)` (or `data.frame(table(df$Gender))` to make a data.frame)

Comment: ok and the question says store in data frame with index key...whats that?